# VBA: Copy number from a string of text and insert into cells below

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a makro in Excel which performs - after pressing a button - the below. I attached some dummy data that is formatted like the actual sheet.

[image]

There are several data blocks that are seperated by headlines in Sheet 1. From these headlines, I want to get a string of numbers and put it into column S for each line with data below that heading. In line 6 the heading says "2000", thus lines 8-19 should have a "2000" in column S and so on. The number I want to get is always after the word "Monthlyaccount" but the lenght of the number can be different - from 1 to 7 digits.
For lines where no data is given (data lines might be recognized by looking if in A is a valid date given) there should just be "ERR" instead of the number.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks so much upfront!

Comment: See [ask] What have you attempted?

Comment: I tried to get the string using =MID but the position is always different. I can recognize which line is a headline but can't bring it on from there...

Answer (score 1):

Say the string (in cell A1) contains "Monthlyaccount" followed by a blank followed by a number followed by another blank.  To extract the number, use:

```
=--LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("Monthlyaccount",A1)+15,9999),-1+FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND("Monthlyaccount",A1)+15,9999)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not quite work. In this case in outputs the word after the number for me but not the number

Answer (score 0):

This does as requested. Paste the following into S3 and drag down

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A2,4)*1),ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A3,4)*1)),S2,IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A3,4)*1),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Monthlyaccount",A1)-14),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("Monthlyaccount",A1)-14))),"ERR"))
```

Comment: It does not look bad as it says ERR in the 3 heading rows but then the cells remain empty, so it does not work completly